# ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found in RHEL 5.11

Tags: python, tensorflow, glibc, rhel

I am using Python 3.5.4 and trying to import tensorflow 1.3.0 in RHEL 5.11 (and also tried in RHEL 6.6) environment. I am getting an issue related to GLIBC 2.14.

Stacktrace is given below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

The GLIBC version in RHEL 5.11 is 2.5 and in RHEL 6.6 is 2.12

Comment: How did you install the tensorflow package?

Comment: @Ankush .. Did you tried installing the GLIB versions

Comment: I installed tensorflow through pip3 with this command:
`pip3 install tensorflow`